# Magic quotes in latest php 5 .5 .x

Tags: php, security

1.I m a beginner .I want to know that "magic quote" is **deprecated** , so do I still need to include in my code?

2.`urldecode()`, `urlencode()`, `htmlentities()` etc do I still need to use ?

3.So, below code won't be needed if everything is fine.

```
/** Check for Magic Quotes and remove them **/
function stripSlashesDeep($value) {
$value = is_array($value) ? array_map(‘stripSlashesDeep’, $value) : stripslashes($value);
return $value;
}

function RemoveMagicQuotes() {
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
$_GET = stripSlashesDeep($_GET );
$_POST = stripSlashesDeep($_POST );
$_COOKIE = stripSlashesDeep($_COOKIE);
}
}
```

Comment: As per [this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) link - ***Warning**
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0*. So you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use one global sanitize function to sanitize every thing. You should consider splitting up your functions for different types of input.

Comment: You missed out the number after *no.* in your comment.

Comment: About "latest php", you mean PHP 7 ? Maybe the title of your post should reflect the exact version (for clarity and for the future ...)

Comment: thanks question 2 bro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic quotes are removed and not useable anymore from PHP 5.3 and later, why? It is up to the programmer to handle and point it where it needs to go. It was meant to be a cure for MySQL injections but failed to do so.

This means that it is up to you that **you** to sanitize **everything** that the "user" can put his furry little claws on. This means at the very least: POST, GET and COOKIE requests.

But escaping like magic quotes did was meant to be used in combination with a database. Using PDO escaping is done automatically and you don't have to worry about it (**IF** properly used of course).

The other functions are still to be used at your own discretion.

Comment: thanks a lot and i dont need to use urldecode(), urlencode(), htmlentities()
right?

Comment: As I said, they are still usable wherever you see fit. And `htmlentities()` is especially handy to avoid XXS attacks (cross site scripting)